# Drawing from a multivarite normal, with "genmn" and "setgmn"

Tags: random, fortran

I am trying to draw random deviates from a multinormal distribution.
There are two subroutines I found online: "setgmn" and "genmn", which are supposed to do exactly that. They are from the "ranlib" library.

http://www.netlib.org/random/

However, I have no clue how those to subroutines are supossed to work together.
Setgmn combines the data in such a way that genmn can uses it. However I struggle wih the "parm" argument I am not exactly sure what I have to pass into it. And how those two subroutines need to be combined to actually work.

I could not find an example online. So I thought maybe someone here already used them or has a link to an example online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [source](http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/f_src/ranlib/ranlib.f90):

First you have to call `setgmn`. This procedure will set the argument `parm` that you have to pass to `getmn`.

```
subroutine setgmn ( meanv, covm, p, parm )
  integer ( kind = 4 ) p
  real ( kind = 4 ) covm(p,p)
  real ( kind = 4 ) meanv(p)
  real ( kind = 4 ) parm(p*(p+3)/2+1)
```

**Parameters**:

`MEANV`: the means of the multivariate normal distribution.

`COVM`:  On input, the covariance matrix of the multivariate distribution.  On output, the information in COVM has been overwritten.

`P`: the number of dimensions.

`PARM`: parameters needed to generate multivariate normal deviates.

`PARM(1)` contains the size of the deviates, P

`PARM(2:P+1)` contains the mean vector.

`PARM(P+2:P*(P+3)/2+1)` contains the upper half of the Cholesky decomposition of the covariance matrix.

---

```
subroutine genmn ( parm, x, work )
  real ( kind = 4 ) parm(*)
  real ( kind = 4 ) work(*)
  real ( kind = 4 ) x(*)
```

**Parameters**:

`PARM(P*(P+3)/2+1)` : parameters set by SETGMN.

`X(P)`: a random deviate from the distribution. Will be the output.

`WORK(P)`: workspace

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative modern implementation of what you need, which works with the Cholesky factorization of the MVN covariance matrix instead of the covariance matrix itself, followed by an example on how to use it:

```
module RandMVN_mod

    implicit none

contains

!***********************************************************************************************************************************
!***********************************************************************************************************************************

    ! Returns a multivariate normal random number.
    function getRandMVN(nd,MeanVec,CholeskyLower,Diagonal) result(RandMVN)
        use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, only: IK => int32, RK => real64
        implicit none
        integer(IK), intent(in) :: nd                   ! dimension of the MVN
        real(RK)   , intent(in) :: MeanVec(nd)          ! The Mean vector of the MVN from which points are drawn
        real(RK)   , intent(in) :: CholeskyLower(nd,nd) ! Lower Triangle of the Cholesky Factorization of the covariance matrix of the MVN
        real(RK)   , intent(in) :: Diagonal(nd)         ! Diagonal terms of the Cholesky Factorization of the covariance matrix of the MVN
        real(RK)                :: RandMVN(nd), dummy
        integer(IK)             :: j,i
        RandMVN = 0._RK
        do j = 1,nd
            dummy = getRandGaus()
            RandMVN(j) = RandMVN(j) + Diagonal(j) * dummy
            do i = j+1,nd
                RandMVN(i) = RandMVN(i) + CholeskyLower(i,j) * dummy
            end do
        end do
        RandMVN = RandMVN + MeanVec
    end function getRandMVN

!***********************************************************************************************************************************
!***********************************************************************************************************************************

    ! returns a normally distributed random number with zero mean and unit variance.
    function getRandGaus()

        use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, only: IK => int32, RK => real64
        implicit none
        integer(IK), save :: iset=0
        real(RK)   , save :: gset
        real(RK)          :: fac,rsq,vec(2)  
        real(RK)          :: getRandGaus

        if (iset == 0) then
            do
                call random_number(vec)
                vec = 2._RK*vec - 1._RK
                rsq = vec(1)**2 + vec(2)**2
                if ( rsq > 0._RK .and. rsq < 1._RK ) exit
            end do
            fac = sqrt(-2._RK*log(rsq)/rsq)
            gset = vec(1)*fac
            getRandGaus = vec(2)*fac
            iset = 1
        else
            getRandGaus = gset
            iset = 0
        endif

    end function getRandGaus

!***********************************************************************************************************************************
!***********************************************************************************************************************************

    ! Returns the the Cholesky factorization of input positive definite matrix PosDefMat
    subroutine getCholeskyFactor(nd,PosDefMat,Diagonal)
        use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, only: IK => int32, RK => real64
        implicit none
        integer(IK), intent(in)    :: nd
        real(RK)   , intent(inout) :: PosDefMat(nd,nd) ! Upper triangle + diagonal is input matrix, lower is output.
        real(RK)   , intent(out)   :: Diagonal(nd)
        real(RK)                   :: summ
        integer(IK)                :: i
        do i=1,nd
            summ = PosDefMat(i,i) - dot_product(PosDefMat(i,1:i-1),PosDefMat(i,1:i-1))
            if (summ <= 0._RK) then

                error stop
            end if
            Diagonal(i) = sqrt(summ)
            PosDefMat(i+1:nd,i) = ( PosDefMat(i,i+1:nd) - matmul(PosDefMat(i+1:nd,1:i-1),PosDefMat(i,1:i-1)) ) / Diagonal(i)
        end do
    end subroutine getCholeskyFactor

!***********************************************************************************************************************************
!***********************************************************************************************************************************

end module RandMVN_mod

program test_RandMVN

    use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, only: IK => int32, RK => real64
    use RandMVN_mod
    implicit none
    integer(IK)             :: isample
    integer(IK) , parameter :: nd = 2           ! dimension of the Multivariate distribution (MVN)
    integer(IK) , parameter :: nsample = 100    ! count of random numbers
    real(RK)    , parameter :: CovMat(nd,nd) = reshape([ 1._RK , 0.5_RK , 0.5_RK , 1._RK ], shape=shape(CovMat))  ! covariance matrix of MVN
    real(RK)    , parameter :: MeanVec(nd) = [ 1._RK , 1._RK ]  ! mean vector of the MVN
    real(RK)                :: CholeskyLower(nd,nd), Diagonal(nd)

    ! get the Cholesky factorization of the Covariance Matrix
    CholeskyLower = CovMat
    call getCholeskyFactor(nd,CholeskyLower,Diagonal)

    ! get random MVN vectors form the MVN distribution
    do isample = 1,nsample
        write(*,"(*(g0,' '))") getRandMVN(nd,MeanVec,CholeskyLower,Diagonal), " ;"
    end do

end program test_RandMVN
```

If you need many random vectors from the same MVN distribution with the same covariance matrix, then passing the Cholesky factorization to the procedure (as done above) makes it far more efficient, for it does not not need to compute it from the input covariance matrix on every call to the procedure.