# how to randomly generate numbers from normal distribution in fortran given mean and standard deviationin fortran

Tags: fortran, fortran90, fortran95

hi im kind of new to using distributions in fortran, and not a very experienced coder, my questions is to generate "n" random numbers from a normal distribution given the mean and standard deviation. and honestly I have no idea about how to get the normal dist or how to us box mueller and all that stuff

the expected output is a number of randomly generated numbers from the normal dist

Comment: You're new here so let me break this to you gently: SO isn't a code-writing service, generally we expect to see an honest and diligent attempt to solve your own problems and we'll pile in with help when you get stuck.  But, absent evidence of that honest and diligent attempt, most of us will do something else with our SO time.

Comment: Please take High Performance Mark's comment to heart. Make your own effort first. But I will point you in a direction. Google 'Box-Muller algorithm'. I suggest you put it in a function where you send it an average and standard deviation and it returns a random number for you. After effort, if you are stuck, then we would be glad to help.

Comment: This can actually be found by googling. At least that is what I did some years ago when I needed it. There are libraries available for this purpose. If you google "fortran normal random number" you will find loads. Some uglier, some nicer. Some faster, some slower. Some serial and some parallel. And if you want your own Box Muller, you should start writing and ask when you hit an actual specific problem, but another alternative is the Ziggurat algorithm. I suggest you to take the Welcome [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Drawing from a multivarite normal, with "genmn" and "setgmn"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51381222/drawing-from-a-multivarite-normal-with-genmn-and-setgmn)